# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am stuck at this piece of code in C#. Its inside an if statement.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Enter your gender : ");
var gender = Console.ReadLine();
if (gender == "boy"){
    Boy.gender == "boy"; // < error here
}
```

The problem states in VSCode is:

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

and this error is pointing at the if statement.

Comment: just replace "==" with "=" in `Boy.gender == "boy"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `==` is like saying "is equal to?". When you say `if(gender == "boy")` you are saying "if gender is equal to "boy".

The error is because you are trying to set Boy.gender to "boy", but since you're using `==` the program thinks you're checking if it's equal to "boy" which doesn't make sense in your context. The technical term for what you want to do is "assign" the value "boy" to Boy.gender.

Comment: The correct usage is a single `=` to change the value of a property.

Comment: damn i just tested it out and it worked! im converting from python to c#. so bad habits :p Thanks <3